# Redirect to index.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, indexing

To respect SEO directives, I want to redirect all traffing coming from:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
http://mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com
mywebsite.com
```

to

```
http://wvw.mywebsite.com/index.html
```

At the moment I use this code, but it doesn't work properly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

All works, but still doesn't redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/index.html` in case of `www.mywebsite.com`.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Try this I hope this helps

Comment: @Pinonirvana If you are satisfied with the answer, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it, selecting the check mark in the upper left of this answer.